# slideUp/slideDown for mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, tablet

I'm developing an application for tablet and mobile use that I want to include slideUp/slideDown animations in. However when testing those on an actual device, they seem to react rather shaky.
Someone knows a solution to this or an alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the JQuery Mobile framework and its included slideup/slidedown animations. The mobile framework uses CSS Transitions to take advantage of hardware acceleration and are very smooth in my experience.

Check out this link for demos: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-transitions.html